# DataNitro - Cannot Import nitroplot in functions.py

Tags: datanitro

I want to import nitroplot in the functions.py to create a custom plot. I cannot seem to do this and keeps on getting error:

> {'type': 'error', 'value': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
>   "27/NitroFileManager.py", line 110, in callFunction\n  File
>   "C:\Program Files\DataNitro\examples\v2\functions.py", line 15,
>   in Waterfall\n    import nitroplot\nImportError: No module named
>   nitroplot\n'}

It seems that it is an issue with the python path. I am using anaconda. Is there an easy way to add the DataNitro packages to the path so that they are included when functions.py is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use nitroplot inside functions.py - that file is specifically for user-defined functions (Python functions that can be called from inside Excel cells).

If you're writing a DataNitro script (one that you use with the "run" button in the DataNitro toolbar) or using the DataNitro shell, you can type "import nitroplot" as usual.